# How to use a if statement inside of a while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, discord, bots

I am currently messing around with a discord bot and I am trying to get it to say E continuously but stop when someone says *E stop. However, with how I have it at the moment it does not work does. Anyone know why?

```
E = False

if message.content.startswith('*E start'):
    E = True
    await message.channel.send('E is beginning!!!')
    while E == True:
       time.sleep(1)
       await message.channel.send('E')
       if message.content.startswith('*E stop'):
            E = False
```

Comment: I am not sure I get your question.  Seems to me like you managed to create a while loop with an if statement just fine, what goes wrong? 

Small tip: use 'while E is True' rather than '=='.

Comment: @Ruben  `is` is no better than `==`. Just `while E:` is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to have a `message.content.startswith` inside a while when using the discord library. What you are looking for is [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class). You need to start and new process and then kill it when someone says `*E stop`. Something like this (not tested):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def sendE(E):
    while E == True:
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.channel.send('E')

E = False
p = type(Process)

if message.content.startswith('*E start'):
    E = True
    await message.channel.send('E is beginning!!!')
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=SendE,args=E)
    p.start()
elif message.content.startswith('*E stop'):
    E = False
    p.kill()
```